# C: execve: I have to implement pipes for a shell, however I cant seem to get the final result out of the second pipe

Tags: c, shell, pipe, exec

This is a homework assignment that has me stumped.  I make two pipes, then two child processes to handle both sides of the pipe.  The first child handles the first command and writes it to the first pipe, the second child handles the second command and writes it to the second pipe.  However, when all is said and done, I read the contents from the second pipe and put it into a buffer and simply printf(buffer).  Its at this step that my code is failing.  I cannot read from the buffer.  I have tested all my method calls such as getWordsBeforePipe() and I know they work.  Do you guys see anything I am missing?

```
// Create the first pipe
pipeStatus = pipe(pfd1);
if (pipeStatus == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}

// create the first child
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    printf("Bad first fork()...\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Here we will run the first command inside of the first child.
if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Im in the first child...\n");
    getWordsBeforePipe(pipeLoc); // get the words before the pipe
    close(pfd1[0]); // close read end because we arent reading anything
    dup2(pfd1[1], 1); // copy to write-end of pfd instead of stdout
    close(pfd1[1]); // close the write end
    firstCommand = execve(pathFirst, beforePipeWords, environ);
    perror("execve"); // we only get here if execve died
    _exit(1);
}


// create the second pipe
    pipeStatus = pipe(pfd2);
if (pipeStatus == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}

// create the second child
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    printf("Bad second fork()...\n");
    exit(1);
}


// Here we will run the second command and put its
// output into the second pipe
// first command business
if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Im in the second child...\n");
    getWordsAfterPipe(pipeLoc); 
    close(pfd1[1]); // close first child write end
    dup2(pfd1[0], 0); // read from the pfd read end instead of stdin
    close(pfd1[0]); // close the read end
    // second command business
    close(pfd2[0]); // close read end because we arent reading anything
    dup2(pfd2[1], 1); // copy to write end of pfd instead of stdout
    close(pfd2[1]);
    secondCommand = execve(pathSecond, afterPipeWords, environ);
    perror("execve"); // we only get here if execve died
    _exit(1);
}



close(pfd1[0]);
close(pfd2[0]);
close(pfd2[1]);


// read from the second pipe and output the final value
readSuccess = read(pfd2[0], buffer, 256);
if (readSuccess < 0) {
    printf("Failure reading the buffer...\n");  // I keep getting this error
    exit(1);
}
if (readSuccess == 0) {
    printf("Empty buffer...\n");
    exit(1);
}

buffer[readSuccess] = '\0';
printf("%s", buffer);
```

Comment: The parent did `close(pfd2[0])` and then tried to read from it. Make sure you're closing the correct ones.

Comment: If I move the close to after the read, the shell just hangs. after the two commands have been executed.

Comment: As well as not closing `pfd2[0]` before reading from it, make sure your child processes' code works properly on its own... maybe one of them is stuck waiting for something?

Comment: @atzero The timing of the closes is correct. As I said, make sure you're closing the **correct** ones.

Comment: Im sorry Barmar, I dont know what you mean by the "correct" ones.

Answer (score 1):

The parent process is doing this:

```
close(pfd2[0]);
```

Followed by this:

```
readSuccess = read(pfd2[0], buffer, 256);
```

You can't read from a file descriptor after it's been closed.

You properly closed both ends of the `pfd1` pair, since the two children read/write from them.  The second child writes to `pfd2[1]`, so the parent should be closing that instead of `pfd2[0]`.

Check that the command specified by `pathFirst` writes to stdout, and that the command specified by `pathSecond` both reads from stdin and writes to stdout.